# How can I change the rootnode of any treestore at runtime?

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4, extjs-mvc

How can I change the rootNode of my treestore at runtime?

Following is my current tree store:

```
Ext.define('rt.store.userinproject', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    folderSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: 'text',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        text: "",
        user: "",
        status: "",
        children: [{
            text: "Project 1",
            pid: 1,
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "Department 1",
                did: 1,
                cls: "folder",
                children: [{
                    text: "User 1",
                    uid: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 2",
                    uid: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 3",
                    uid: 3,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 4",
                    uid: 4,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 5",
                    uid: 5,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "Department 2",
                did: 2,
                cls: "folder",
                children: [{
                    text: "User 6",
                    uid: 6,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 7",
                    uid: 7,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 8",
                    uid: 8,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 9",
                    uid: 9,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 10",
                    uid: 10,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "Department 3",
                did: 3,
                cls: "folder",
                children: [{
                    text: "User 11",
                    uid: 11,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 12",
                    uid: 12,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 13",
                    uid: 13,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 14",
                    uid: 14,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 15",
                    uid: 15,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            text: "Project 2",
            pid: 2,
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "Department 1",
                did: 1,
                cls: "folder",
                children: [{
                    text: "User 1",
                    uid: 1,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 2",
                    uid: 2,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 3",
                    uid: 3,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 4",
                    uid: 4,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 5",
                    uid: 5,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "Department 2",
                did: 2,
                cls: "folder",
                children: [{
                    text: "User 16",
                    uid: 16,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 17",
                    uid: 17,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 18",
                    uid: 18,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 19",
                    uid: 19,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 20",
                    uid: 20,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                text: "Department 3",
                did: 3,
                cls: "folder",
                children: [{
                    text: "User 21",
                    uid: 21,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 22",
                    uid: 22,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 23",
                    uid: 23,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 24",
                    uid: 24,
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    text: "User 25",
                    uid: 25,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Currently I am able to show whole tree from root Node in my treepanel.

Now in store above I want to make "Project 1" as my root node when user click on project 1
and "project 2" as my root node when user click on project 2.

Is this possible? If so, how? Let me know if you need anything from me.

Comment: What do you mean by changing rootNode? Do you want to change a text or all hierarchy?

Comment: @TheHorse Thanks for reply. I can say I want to show only part of hierarchy. I do not know if it is possible with extjs. I have edited my question. In my store above I want to make "Project 1" as rootNode when user click on project 1 and same for project 2. I hope this clears question further

Answer (score 3):

**1.** If you are trying to modify some part of the existing root first you need to get hold of the root node. You can get hold of your root node using `getRootNode()` available with your `TreeStore`. example:

```
 var node = treeObject.getStore().getRootNode();
```

Now, to modify the data, you can make use of `data` property. For example, if you need to change the root node's text, you can:

```
node.data.text = 'New Root';   // You can access any other property of your node's data model the same way
```

**2.** If you need to replace the entire node you can make use of the `setRootNode()` which is also available with your `TreeStore`. You will have to pass the appropriate data model used for your TreeStore.

Since, you are trying to replace your root, you definitly need to use `setRootNode()`. Here is an example code replacing the root:

```
//your tree click handler...
itemclick : function(view,rec,it,inx,ev) {

    var root = view.getTreeStore().getRootNode();
    var newRoot = root.getChildAt(inx).copy('xx',true);                 
    view.getTreeStore().setRootNode(newRoot);                   
}
```

Ideally, this code should work. but there is a [small bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134844-tree-node-copy%28deep%29-not-working-%284.0.1%29&highlight=tree%20copy) in `copy()` that causes to break this code. A temporary solution (I would not recommend modifying library files) is available at the forum (refer the above link).

Another way would be to code your own `copy` code like:

```
var root = view.getTreeStore().getRootNode();
var newRoot = root.getChildAt(inx);
view.getTreeStore().setRootNode(newRoot); 
// for each child in newRoot, create child for the newly assigned root.
```

Comment: @Abdel Olakara Thanks for reply. I edited my question to clear it further. I have list of projects and what I want to do is, show tree as root = "Project 1" when user clicks on Project 1 and root = "Project 2" for click on project 2 and so on.. Hope this helps.

Comment: @amar4kintu you can do it using the second method. Use the setRootNode() to make 'Project2' as your root node. but my question is, how do your use go to Project1 after that?

Comment: @Abdel Olakara Thanks for reply. Currently I am using border layout in which on left hand side, I have list of projects and on right hand side I have take tabbed panel and one of the tab of that panel is users in project. so when user clicks on project on left side I want to show list of users in that project. Hope this makes sense. From the above store do you think it is possible to change roots to what I need on user click?

Comment: @amar4kintu.. did you try the second method explained above? if you did, you will know it worked or not!

Comment: @Abdel Olakara Thanks for reply. Yes I tried second method but tree view is not updating after that so it shows empty tree. what I did is this -> usertree.getStore().setRootNode(usertree.getStore().getRootNode().getChildAt(0)); usertree.view.refresh();  It seems that this is the problem with treepanel currently. If you have any other ideas than let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Abdel Olakara Thanks for reply. I tried your solution. What is happening is store rootNode changes to new node but tree panel is not refreshing it becomes blank as soon as store root change occurs. I also tried usertree.view.refresh(); but it is not helping. do you have any idea?